# Use Wilson theorem to show that $63! + 1 \equiv 0 \mod ~ 71$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Use Wilson theorem to show that $63! + 1 \equiv 0 \mod ~ 71$.

71 is prime then Wilson theorem says that $(71-1)!+1=0 \mod ~ 71$ i.e $70!+1\equiv 0 \mod ~ 71$ then how to proceed further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to show that $70! \equiv 63! \mod 71$, so it suffices to show that $70 \cdot 69\cdot 68\cdot 67\cdot 66 \cdot 65 \cdot 64 \equiv 1 \mod 71$. This holds because of $70 \cdot 69\cdot 68\cdot 67\cdot 66 \cdot 65 \cdot 64 \equiv (-1)\cdot (-2)\cdot (-3)\cdot (-4)\cdot (-5)\cdot (-6)\cdot (-7) \equiv -720 \cdot 7 \equiv -10 \cdot 7 \equiv -70 \equiv 1 \mod 71$

Comment: Would you please explain the theorem that you have applied  to show 70⋅69⋅68⋅67⋅66⋅65⋅64≡(−1)⋅(−2)⋅(−3)⋅(−4)⋅(−5)⋅(−6)⋅(−7)mod71

Comment: It seams that the theorem applied is of the style $a\cdot b(mod ~m)\equiv a(mod ~m)\cdot b(mod~m)$. If I am correct, please give me a reference of the theorem.

Comment: @user1942348 yes, you are correct. proof: write $a=cm+d, b=em+f$, then it follows that $ab = m(cem+de+fc)+df$, so $(a \mod m)(b \mod m) = df = (ab \mod m)$

Answer (score 8):

Hint: $64\times 65 \dots \times 70 \equiv -7\times -6 \dots \times -1$

To break it down further try

> $(7\times 5 \times 2)\times (6\times 4\times 3)$

Comment: also famous example, conjectured the largest, $7! + 1 = w^2,$ and $w$ is, well...

Comment: could not recall the name, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem